# Input text value not changed with <p> element onclick

Tags: javascript

I want to change my Input text value by clicking on a **p** html element.

The code snippet is like this

```
input type="text" id="query" name="quer"  runat="server"/>
p id="demo" click="myFunction()"></p>
```

myFunction() is in abc.js file that is included in the main Html file.

```
function myFunction(){
var elem = document.getElementById("query"); // Get text field
elem.setAttribute('value','Insert a correct email');
}
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: on p tag the event should be onclick, not click

Comment: if you found any answer by youself then share it with us, or if you have answer from below then mark that as 'accepted answer'. It'll help others to find solution of similar problem like you quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The event on **p** tag should be *onclick*, not click. Update your **p** tag as following,

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</p>
```

*That's it, your code just works fine.*

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/dL038yf1/)

***References :*** [***onclick***](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Answer (score 1):

`click` should be `onclick`

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()"></p>
```

However, I suggest you use `.value` over `setAttribute`:

```
elem.value = 'Insert a correct email';
```

`setAttribute` is actually changing **HTML attribute**, you can see it if you open devtool and observe the structure. But what you want is manipulate the **DOM property**.

For example, you have `<input value="123">` in an HTML file. And in page you input something, say "456". Now you can see the difference:

```
document.querySelector('input').getAttribute('value') // '123', HTML attribute
document.querySelector('input').value // '456', DOM property
```

At the beginning, HTML attribute will populate to DOM property as initial value. But once you touched DOM property, e.g. you input something in the field, after that changing HTML attribute will **NOT** dynamically change DOM property. And by the way, on submitting form, the value actually sent out is DOM property, not HTML attribute.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("query"); // Get text field
    elem.value = 'Insert a correct email';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="query" name="quer"  runat="server"/>
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</p>
```